# Error while installing new version of Slack: staging user ID and other errors

Tags: windows, windows-7, slack, squirrel.windows

Today my Slack said that to continue using it I need to download the latest version. I've downloaded it, but when I try to install I get "Installation has failed" message (My OS is Windows 7 64-bit.)

```
2016-07-27 12:52:37> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install .
2016-07-27 12:52:40> Program: Starting install, writing to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
2016-07-27 12:52:42> Program: About to install to: C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack
2016-07-27 12:52:48> CheckForUpdateImpl: Couldn't write out staging user ID, this user probably shouldn't get beta anything: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\packages\.betaId'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.CheckForUpdateImpl.getOrCreateStagedUserId()
2016-07-27 12:52:48> CheckForUpdateImpl: Failed to load local releases, starting from scratch: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\packages\RELEASES'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Squirrel.Utility.LoadLocalReleases(String localReleaseFile)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.CheckForUpdateImpl.<CheckForUpdate>d__3f.MoveNext()
2016-07-27 12:52:49> CheckForUpdateImpl: Reading RELEASES file from C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
2016-07-27 12:52:50> CheckForUpdateImpl: First run or local directory is corrupt, starting from scratch
2016-07-27 12:52:54> ApplyReleasesImpl: Writing files to app directory: C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0
2016-07-27 12:53:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\content_resources_200_percent.pak to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\content_resources_200_percent.pak
2016-07-27 12:53:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\d3dcompiler_47.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\d3dcompiler_47.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\content_shell.pak to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\content_shell.pak
2016-07-27 12:53:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\ffmpeg.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\ffmpeg.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\icudtl.dat to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\icudtl.dat
2016-07-27 12:53:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\libEGL.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\libEGL.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\libGLESv2.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\libGLESv2.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\LICENSE to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\LICENSE
2016-07-27 12:53:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\msvcp120.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\msvcp120.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\msvcr120.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\msvcr120.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\natives_blob.bin to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\natives_blob.bin
2016-07-27 12:53:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\node.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\node.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\PerMonitorDpi.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\PerMonitorDpi.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\ReactiveUI.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\ReactiveUI.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\Splat.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\Splat.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\slack.exe to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\slack.exe
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\squirrel.exe to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\squirrel.exe
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\SlackNotifier.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\SlackNotifier.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\snapshot_blob.bin to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\snapshot_blob.bin
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\System.Reactive.Core.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\System.Reactive.Core.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\System.Reactive.Interfaces.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\System.Reactive.Interfaces.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\ui_resources_200_percent.pak to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\ui_resources_200_percent.pak
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\System.Reactive.Linq.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\System.Reactive.Linq.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\vccorlib120.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\vccorlib120.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\xinput1_3.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\xinput1_3.dll
2016-07-27 12:53:24> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\lib\net45\System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.dll to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.dll
2016-07-27 12:55:30> ApplyReleasesImpl: Squirrel Enabled Apps: [C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.1.0\slack.exe]
2016-07-27 12:55:37> ApplyReleasesImpl: Starting fixPinnedExecutables
2016-07-27 12:55:37> ApplyReleasesImpl: Examining Pin: Far Manager 2.lnk
2016-07-27 12:55:37> ApplyReleasesImpl: Examining Pin: Hide all windows.lnk
2016-07-27 12:55:37> ApplyReleasesImpl: Examining Pin: Microsoft Outlook 2010.lnk
2016-07-27 12:55:37> ApplyReleasesImpl: Examining Pin: Windows Explorer.lnk
2016-07-27 12:55:37> ApplyReleasesImpl: Examining Pin: Windows Live Mail.lnk
2016-07-27 12:55:37> ApplyReleasesImpl: Fixing up tray icons
2016-07-27 12:55:37> ApplyReleasesImpl: cleanDeadVersions: for version 2.1.0
2016-07-27 12:55:37> ApplyReleasesImpl: cleanDeadVersions: exclude folder app-2.1.0
2017-07-04 12:07:16> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install .
2017-07-04 12:07:16> Program: Starting install, writing to C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
2017-07-04 12:07:16> Program: About to install to: C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\SourceTree
2017-07-04 12:07:17> CheckForUpdateImpl: Couldn't write out staging user ID, this user probably shouldn't get beta anything: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\slebedev\AppData\Local\SourceTree\packages\.betaId'.
```

The full SquirrelSetup.log is here: https://pastebin.com/tRjHXg1D

Comment: I would recommend to a) open a ticket with the Slack team b) use the browser version of Slack in the meantime: https://slack.com/

Comment: Erik Kalkoken - thanks, I've already opened a ticket, but I did not know about browser version:)